# .cm domains for content management systems

Tags: seo, domains, cms

The `.cm` domains belong to Cameroon.

Are they suitable for hosting a content management system script (not targeted to Cameroon users) ? The wikipedia page mentions that I need a company registered in Cameroon in order to register one, but the Africa Registry page says"no restrictions".

`.cms` doesn't seem to exist. I only found this old post from 2011:
https://www.linkedin.com/groups/CMS-TopLevel-Domain-1840166.S.69579022?view=&gid=1840166&type=member&item=69579022

Comment: Why do you have to use .cm or .cms, what's wrong with .com (for example) instead of trying to use a TLD for not its intended purpose?

Comment: Well, mainly because most of the names that I have thought of are take on.com :(

Comment: is it available on any other recognised non-country TLD (like .net, .biz, .org)?

Comment: nope. it's a 4 letter name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a purely technical level, you shouldn't have problems having a site there.

However, the message a .cm domain gives is not "Content Management System", but "From Cameroon".  If things like SEO are important, such signals are not going to help you in other countries.

A list of available domains (and what they are for) is available on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains).
Of the new domains, .website would probably be the most applicable.